# jQuery autocomplete with python Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, autocomplete, flask

Many similar questions as mine were asked before and I tried all the solutions, only to find it didn't help.

I am having a text box for which autocomplete needs to be incorporated with values fetched from db based on the input given. I am using javascript in the client side and using python in the server side. I am using flask framework for this activity.

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="auto"/>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
      source: "{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",
      minLength: 1
     });
    });
</script>
```

**python:**

```
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    value = request.args.get('term')
    sql = "select name from data_table where name like '%"+value+"%'"
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    data_list = []
    cursor = conn.execute(sql)
    for row in cursor:
        data_list.append(row[0])
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(json_list=data_list)
```

For every key entered in the textbox, the python method is getting called. The problem is how I return the results to javascript. Everytime I enter a key I get 500 Internal server error.

In autocomplete snippet, if `source: "{{url_for('autocomplete')}}".json_list` it throws error too.

But the autocomplete works fine if values are given as array in the javascript side and when no python activity is involved.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need turn on DEBUG mode and see flask log/console to see what exactly throw 500 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a 500 error code in an ajax call means there's some problem with the server-size code itself. One thing i would check is what if no rows are returned, you'll get an error in `data_list.append(row[0])`, since row is not a list (probably a None), and row[0] would fail.

Trap your error using try/except and handle it on the client side (if None is returned javascript should do nothing- autocomplete should be able to deal with a null value from an ajax call, so you're left with mostly making sure your server-side python works for all inputs).

A side note: don't connect/disconnect to the database each and every time the users changes inputs. That's a lot of overhead. Use Flask-SQLAlchemy for database connection management. It's more elegant, faster and less resource demanding than what you're doing above.